# Custom block padding control (via support) initialization

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, block-editor

I'm building a custom block control.  I'm trying to let Gutenberg handle formatting via the support section of the **block.json** file as follows:

```
  "supports": {
    "type": "object",
    "anchor":  true,
    "color":  {
      "color":    true,
      "background":  true,
      "link":      false,
      "gradients":  false
    },
    "typography": {
      "fontSize":    true,
      "lineHeight":  true
    },
    "spacing": {
      "margin": false,
      "padding": true,
      "__experimentalDefaultControls": {
        "padding": true
      }
    }
  },
```

If I'm reading the documentation correctly, this is how I configured the initialization of padding:

```
  "attributes": {
    ...
    "style": {
      "type": "object",
      "default": {
        "color": {
          "color": "#111",
          "background": "#eee"
        },
        "spacing": {
          "padding": {
            "padding": { "top": "3px", "right": "20px",
            "bottom": "6px", "left": "2px" }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    ...
  },
```

When editing a new control doesn't have the preset values.

[Edit] I'm finding different variation of not end-to-end fully working for fontSize, color and background.

[Edit] I added changes from Stokesman's comment, but still not working.

Comment: I think you'll find this discussion helpful: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/discussions/53603

Comment: I'd had the default values in one version, but didn't work.  I was hoping the experimental setting would help but I'm not seeing it rendered.

Comment: Your updated example is incorrectly nesting `padding` under `padding` in the `default.spacing`.

Comment: Thanks, yes `style.default.spacing.padding: { "top": "3px", "right": "20px", "bottom": "6px", "left": "2px" }` works as expected